# How to use interpolation value from other component?

Tags: angular

I am using angular

In my HTML file, I am using like `{{ interpolationvalue() }}`

In TS File,

```
interpolationvalue()
{
this.route.navigate(['\x'])
}
```

How can I use this interpolation function outside ts file and I need to import in my HTML file.

Is it possible?

Help me with this

Comment: Can you be more precise please ? In which HTML would you like to use it ? In an other component ? Could you export this method in a service ?

Comment: @Random Actually what I meant was this interpolationvalue() function I need to use in different files. This makes the code duplication.So I thought of using this function commonly in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make an Injectable:

```
@Injectable()
export class InterpolationUtils {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  public interpolationvalue() {
    this.router.navigate(['\x'])
  }
}
```

and in any component:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyFeatureComponent {

  constructor(private interpolationUtils: InterpolationUtils) {}

  myMethod() {
    // do stuff
    this.interpolationUtils.interpolatevalue();
  }
}
```